# How can I add bar (columns) charts that has a trend line above. Currently I have line charts

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I tried to have stacked bars (columns) charts with a trend line above.

Right now with below codes I was able to have a line charts

How may I change it to have line charts? (Sorry for some Japanese wordings included)

```
def chart_returns_different_country(bq):
    count_list = ['民生用電気機器', '重電機器受注生産品']
    field_list = ['Refridgerator','Refridgerator Larger than 401 Litre','Automobiles equipment','Construction equipment']

    input_1 = widgets.Dropdown(options = count_list,
        value = '民生用電気機器',
        description = 'Choose a category', 
        style={'description_width': 'initial'},
        layout=Layout(width='50%', height='40px')
    )

    input_2 = widgets.Dropdown(options = field_list,
                              value='Refridgerator',
                              description='機器')
    
    start_time = date(2020, 4, 30)
    input_3 = widgets.DatePicker(description='Choose start date', disabled=False, value=start_time)
    
    end_time = datetime.today()
    input_4 = widgets.DatePicker(description='Choose end date', disabled=False, value=end_time)
    
    民生用電気機器_電気冷蔵庫 ={'House Appliance Refridgerator': 'JNESHQER Index'}
    民生用電気機器_電気冷蔵庫うち401L以上 = {'House Appliance Refridgerator Over 401 Litre':'JNESHQRO Index'}
    
    重電機器受注生産品_自動車 = {'Heavy Electric Equipment - Automobiles': 'JPCITOTL Index'}
    重電機器受注生産品_建設業= {'Heavy Electric Equipment - Construction':'JNHECONS Index'}
    
    

    field_0 = {'Refridgerator' : 民生用電気機器_電気冷蔵庫,
            'Refridgerator Larger than 401 Litre' : 民生用電気機器_電気冷蔵庫うち401L以上, 'Automobiles equipment' : 重電機器受注生産品_自動車,
            'Construction equipment' : 重電機器受注生産品_建設業}     

    fig = go.Figure()

    #fig.update_layout(barmode = 'stack')
    fig.update_traces(textfont_size=18, textangle=0, textposition ="outside", cliponaxis =False)
    fig.layout.xaxis.title.text = 'Date'
    fig.layout.yaxis.title.font.size=18
    fig.update_layout(template ='plotly_dark',height=700)
    fig.update_layout(xaxis={'side':'bottom'})
    fig.update_xaxes(tickfont_size=18, tickangle=0)
    fig.update_yaxes(tickfont_size=18)
    fig.update_layout(xaxis=dict(showgrid=False), yaxis=dict(showgrid=False))
    fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])
    
    fig_w = go.FigureWidget(fig)
    
        
    def update_chart(evt=None):
        
        global field_0
        global data_item
        
        if  input_1.value == "民生用電気機器": 
            field_0 = {'Refridgerator' : 民生用電気機器_電気冷蔵庫,
            'Refridgerator Larger than 401 Litre' : 民生用電気機器_電気冷蔵庫うち401L以上}
        

        else : field_0 = {'Automobiles equipment' : 重電機器受注生産品_自動車,
            'Construction equipment' : 重電機器受注生産品_建設業}
       
        data_item = {'Value': bq.data.px_last(dates=bq.func.range(input_3.value, input_4.value),fill='NA',per='M')} #currency='USD'
        
        
        selected_index = field_0.get(input_2.value)
        global bql_request
        bql_request = bql.Request(list(selected_index.values()), data_item)
        df = bql.combined_df(bq.execute(bql_request))
        df.index = df.index.map(dict(zip(selected_index.values(), selected_index.keys())))
        df = df.reset_index()
        df = df.pivot(index='DATE', columns='ID', values='Value')
        df_plot = df.copy()
        df_plot.reset_index(inplace=True)
        df_plot.set_index('DATE', inplace=True)
        
        
        x = df_plot.index
        fig_w.data= []
       
        for i in range(len(df_plot.columns.values)):
            if i == 0:
                fig_w.add_trace(go.Scatter(name= df_plot.columns.values[0], x= x, y= df_plot[df_plot.columns.values[0]], mode='lines',  yaxis='y1'), secondary_y=False)
                fig_w.add_trace(go.Bar(name= df_plot.columns.values[0], x= x, y= df_plot[df_plot.columns.values[0]], mode='lines',  yaxis='y1'), secondary_y=False)
            else:
                try:
                    fig_w.add_trace(go.Scatter(name=df_plot.columns.values[i], x= x, y= df_plot[df_plot.columns.values[i]], mode='lines', yaxis='y2'), secondary_y=True)
                    fig_w.add_trace(go.Bar(name=df_plot.columns.values[i], x= x, y= df_plot[df_plot.columns.values[i]], mode='lines', yaxis='y2'), secondary_y=True)
                    # fig_w.set_ylabel('Others', color = 'r')
                except:
                    pass
        y_label1  =  df_plot.columns.values[0]   
        y_label2 = 'Others'
        fig_w.update_layout(yaxis = dict(title = y_label1), yaxis2 = dict(title = y_label2))
                            
        fig_w.layout.xaxis.title.text = 'Date'
        
        fig_w.update_xaxes(tickangle=45)
        fig_w.update_layout(template='plotly_dark', height=700, font_family="Arial", legend_font_size=16, font=dict(
            family="Arial",
            size=18, ))
        fig_w.update_layout(xaxis=dict(tickvals=x))
        fig_w.for_each_xaxis(lambda x: x.update(showgrid=False))
        fig_w.for_each_yaxis(lambda x: x.update(showgrid=False))             
        
    update_chart()

    input_1.observe(update_chart, names='value', type='change')
    input_2.observe(update_chart, names='value', type='change')
    input_3.observe(update_chart, names='value', type='change')
    input_4.observe(update_chart, names='value', type='change')
    bql_request =[str(bql.Request(list(field_0.get('Refridgerator').values()), data_item)),
                 str(bql.Request(list(field_0.get('Refridgerator Larger than 401 Litre').values()), data_item)),
                 str(bql.Request(list(field_0.get('Automobiles equipment').values()), data_item)), str(bql.Request(list(field_0.get('Construction equipment').values()), data_item))]
    return {'Chart': widgets.VBox([input_1, input_2, input_3, input_4, fig_w]), 'BQL Query': '\n'.join(bql_request)}
   
chart_returns_different_country(bq)['Chart']
```

I have tried `fig.add_trace(go.Bar()` but did not work

Comment: Update: I have able to added bar and trend line above with the codes below:

Comment: for i in range(len(df_plot.columns.values)):
            if i == 0:
                fig_w.add_trace(go.Scatter(name='Trend' , x= x, y= df_plot[df_plot.columns.values[0]], mode='lines',  yaxis='y1'), secondary_y=False)
                fig_w.add_trace(go.Bar(name= df_plot.columns.values[0], x= x, y= df_plot[df_plot.columns.values[0]]))
                fig.update_traces(bar_color='blue')

Comment: else:
                try:
                    fig_w.add_trace(go.Scatter(name=df_plot.columns.values[i], x= x, y= df_plot[df_plot.columns.values[i]], mode='lines', yaxis='y2'), secondary_y=True)
                    # fig_w.set_ylabel('Others', color = 'r')
                except:
                    pass

Comment: May I know how can I possible change the colors of the bars and the trend line? 

I think it need fig.update_layout() somewhere but not sure where to add the command line to

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that I can do via:

f i == 0:
fig_w.add_trace(go.Scatter(name='Trend' , x= x, y= df_plot[df_plot.columns.values[0]], mode='lines',  yaxis='y1',marker= dict(color='rgb(255,255,255)')), secondary_y=False)
fig_w.add_trace(go.Bar(name= df_plot.columns.values[0], x= x, y= df_plot[df_plot.columns.values[0]],marker= dict(color='rgb(243,107,28)')))

```
        else:
            try:
                fig_w.add_trace(go.Scatter(name=df_plot.columns.values[i], x= x, y= df_plot[df_plot.columns.values[i]], mode='lines', yaxis='y2'), secondary_y=True)
                # fig_w.set_ylabel('Others', color = 'r')
            except:
                pass
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).